# Error in Installation of Module

Tags: python

I'm trying to install the module `zipline` into Python 2.7 on Eclipse. I'm running the file with the following but the Error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` results. I need help figuring this out.

```
import pip
pip install zipline
```

Edit: I have tried `pip install zipline` on the Command line as seen in the picture below but to no avail.

[image]

Comment: You don't run `pip install foo` **inside a Python script**, you run it **on the command line**. Then in your script you can just `import zipline` - you don't need to `import pip` at all.

Comment: That picture shows you trying to run `pip` in **the Python interpreter**, which is **still not the command line**...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip` is a linux command, not a [tag: python] command. Thus, exit from the python interpreter and run the `pip install` in your Linux interpreter and it will run fine.

After installation, open your python interpreter and run

```
import zipline
```

And it should run fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run pip install from the command line. Please note you also need to install numpy.

Answer (score 0):

Run in `command line`

```
pip install zipline
```

OR

```
sudo pip install zipline
```

if any permission issues

Then in file, just import it

```
import zipline
```